# Angular 2 Google Map with Multiple Markers

Tags: google-maps, angular, typescript

I'm currently developing an Angular2 project which using Google Maps.

I'm trying to display the markers and multiple markers around the area.
I've got the map working but can't seem to marker.

```
<div class="google-maps"></div>



constructor(private _elementRef:ElementRef) {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let el = this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.google-maps');
    GoogleMapsLoader.load((google) => {
      let myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403,-78.5463);
      new google.maps.Map(el, {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

      });
      new google.maps.Marker(el,{ 
        draggable: true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: myLatlng,
            title:"Hello World!"
          });
        }); 
  }
```

Comment: any errors logged?

Comment: Hope this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example

Comment: no error log massage

Comment: try this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628000/facing-difficulty-with-angular-2-google-map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The marker function doesnt seem to match the official docs [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers).

```
 let map = new google.maps.Map(el, {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

      });
 let marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
        draggable: true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,//set map created here
            title:"Hello World!"
          });
```

Comment: you can call the same `new Marker` with different `position` and `title` values on the same map..have a function which creates markers and call whenever you need.

Comment: @suraj Hi, do you know how to add infowindow to markers with their allocated content? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45252867/ionic-2-angular-2-adding-array-of-markers-with-infowindow-on-google-map)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code this work my project

Google Official Doc [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)

```
import  GoogleMapsLoader  from 'google-maps';
import  { google } from 'google-maps';

ngAfterViewInit() {

let el = this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.contact-us');

GoogleMapsLoader.KEY = 'g4554645645645645645646';

GoogleMapsLoader.load((google) => {

let myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.5454, 90.8785);

let map =  new google.maps.Map(el, {

    center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.8787878, 90.87878),

    zoom: 18,

    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

let marker =  new google.maps.Marker({ 
      draggable: true,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title:"Hello World!"
    });

});
```

Template.html

```
 <div class="contact-us" style="position: relative; height: 470px;"></div>
```